# PDF in Preview won't get smaller than half the screen on Ventura

Tags: macos, preview, ventura

I recently updated from Big Sur to Ventura (13.2.1) and the behavior of Preview changed. I can no longer make the Preview window less that almost half the screen wide! Is there a way to change this? Was this a purposeful change? According to Wikipedia, Big Sur had the same version of Preview, 11.0. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: I can make a PDF window quite small (though I do have a large screen) -- about 700 pixels (scaled). I don't think there has been a significant change in Preview. What size screen do you have?